# NSWindowController multiple nib problem

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

MainController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface MainController : NSWindowController {
    NSWindowController *sc;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *txt1;
}

-(IBAction)executeButtonClick:(id)sender;
-(void)setTxt1Text:(NSString *)txt;

@end
```

MainController.m

```
#import "MainController.h"
#import "SecondController.h"


@implementation MainController

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    sc = nil;
}

-(IBAction)executeButtonClick:(id)sender;
{
    if (sc == nil)
    {
        sc = [[SecondController alloc] initWithMController:self];
    }
    [sc showWindow:self];
    [[sc window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}

-(void)setTxt1Text:(NSString *)txt;
{
    [txt1 setStringValue:txt];
}

@end
```

SecondController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface SecondController : NSWindowController {
    NSWindowController *mController;
}
-(id)initWithMController:(NSWindowController *)mctrl;
-(IBAction)testButtonClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

### Here's the problem reside:

SecondController.m

```
#import "SecondController.h"


@implementation SecondController

    -(id)initWithMController:(NSWindowController *)mctrl;
    {
        self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"SecondWindow"];
        mController = mctrl;
        NSLog(@"%@",mController);
        return self;
    }

    -(IBAction)testButtonClick:(id)sender;
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",mController);
        [mController setTxt1Text:@"Test Success"];
    }

    @end
```

Logs:

```
2011-05-09 15:41:10.337 MultiWindow[4334:a0f] <MainController: 0x1005295b0>
2011-05-09 15:41:11.336 MultiWindow[4334:a0f] (null)
```

Why mController became null ? Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging self in both places as well (in addition to mController). My guess is you will find that you have more than one SecondController object (perhaps one created in code through -[MainController executeButtonClick:] and the other in your SecondWindow nib?).

Comment: Yeah I had more than SecondController object. File Owner made me confused, thanks!